# How to change the color of text in tabs of tabbed activity?

Tags: android, tabs

```
     TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos"));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Games"));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Music"));
```

Videos,games and music is coming in white.

With my current theme, it's coming (text in tab bar)white in color.I want to retain my theme and just want to change the color of text from white to any other color.

Comment: tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));

Comment: yes it worked for me  color changed to black

Comment: if it helped then Upvote and accept my answer tHappy Coding

Comment: just waiting for the minimum time to accept the answer

Comment: Cool, Happy to help Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Games"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Music"));

tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tab_text_act</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text</item>
</style>
```

This should allow you to change the color of the text to whatever you want

Comment: Thanks, @2D3D but Rakshit answer is short and to the point What I need